# リダイレクトでrootユーザしか書き込めない場所にsudoで書き込むには

Tags: bash, sudo

bashでの質問です。OSはCentOSです。

仮に`/etc`のようなrootユーザ以外は書き込めない場所にファイルを書き込もうとしたところ、

```
sudo ls > /etc/test.txt
```

とすると、lsコマンドはrootで実行できますが、>以降のファイルはroot権限ではありません。
このような場所でも書き込めるような方法はありますか？
一応、suコマンドでrootになってから実行すると実行可能ですが、su以外でお願いしたく。

ご存知の方、ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo ls | sudo tee /etc/test.txt
```

でいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 9):

`man sudo`を眺めていると出て来る例を参考に、

```
sudo sh -c "ls > /etc/test.txt"
```